# Why I split a specific array in a two-dimensional array but it also split another array as well

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image]

I have never faced this problem before and I really don't know how or why this can be occuring. Can anyone explain this for me?

There is also an image as well and it is on the top. As you can see in the picture, the last array didn't change while other arrays changed.

Here is the method (where I am facing my problem)

```
    Object.prototype.createObject = function(name){
            this[name] = [];
        }
        Array.prototype.matrixCreator = function(a3,b3){
            var length = this.length;
            if((this[1][0] && this[0][1]) === undefined){
                var array1 = new Array(length-1);
                for(var d3=0;d3<length-1;d3++){
                    array1[d3] = new Array(length-1);
                }
            }else{
                var array = new Array(length);
                for(var e3=0;e3<length;e3++){
                    array[e3] = new Array(length);
                }
            }
            for(var c3=0;c3<length;c3++){
                this[c3].splice(b3,1);
                document.writeln(this[c3]);
                if(c3 === a3){              // this prototype doesn't support the new design of matrix about spliting
                if(c3===0){
                    this.splice(a3,1);
                    length--;
                }else{
                    this.splice(a3,1);
                    c3--;
                    length--;
                }
                }
            }
            var f3;
            var g3;
            if((this[1][0] && this[0][1]) === undefined){
                array1[0][0] = this[a][b];
                for(var h3=1;h3<length;h3++){
                    for(var i3=1;i3<length;i3++){
                        array1[h3][i3] = this[h3][i3];
                    }
                }
                return array1;
            }else{
            array[0][0] = this[a3][b3];
            for(var j3=1;j3<length+1;j3++){
                for(var l3=1;l3<length+1;l3++){
                    f3 = j3-1;
                    g3 = l3-1;
                    array[j3][l3] = this[f3][g3];
                }
            }
            return array;
            }
            }
 // Here is the test code for my method:

var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.addEventListener("click",function(){
            var array10 = new Array(4);
            for(var b=0;b<4;b++){
                array10[b] = [];
            }
            var array3 = [1,2,3,4];
            var array4 = [5,6,7,8];
            for(var c=0;c<4;c++){
                array10[c]=array3;
                array10[c+1]=array4;
            }
            var n = array10.length;
            var controller = -1;
            var key=0;var key1=0;
            var obj ={};
            var array=[]; var array1=[];
            var flow=0;
            while(key1 === 0){
                for(var a=0;a<n;a++){
                    var string = "array" + a;
                    if(key==0){
                        obj.createObject(string);
                        array = array10.matrixCreator(0,a);
                        obj[string].push(array);
                        document.writeln(obj[string]);
                    }else{
                        for(var d=1;d<flow;d++){
                            array = obj[string][controller].matrixCreator(1,d);
                            obj[string].push(array);
                            document.writeln(obj[string]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                    key=1;
                    controller++;
                    flow = obj[string][controller].length;
                    if(flow === 3){
                        break;
                    }
            }
    });
```

html code:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="press here"/>
```

Comment: please add the source code as text to the question.

Comment: the source code is in the picture

Comment: yes, and i can copy the picture in my ide.

Comment: ide ? can you define this word for me pls

Comment: integrated development environment.

Comment: anyone there ? i am so alone here

Comment: maybe you add an example of the original array and what should happen after the "splitting".

Comment: thanks god, you are back

Comment: ok ,i just add a picture to show its first state

Comment: the picture does not really help.

Comment: i am sorry, i just add another

Comment: as you can see, the array3 and array2 have changed from 4 elements to 3 elements simultaneously when i am spliting a specific array

Comment: the array4, however, has different value from the array2 and array 3 so that it won't be splited

Comment: if i would know, what you would do, i could answer your question.

Comment: oh, i am trying  to split matrix to smaller matrixs until the matrixs' size is 2.

Comment: you could add an example.

Comment: like this: [1 2 3 4][2 3 4 5][3 4 5 6][4 5 6 7]. Assume that it is a matrix of size 4. Then when i spliting --> [3 4 5][4 5 6][5 6 7]. i remove the first row and the first column.

Comment: Is there any explaination? or i have to do it in another way?

Comment: ok, i understand now. how do you get the split coordinates from?

Comment: the coordinates are the first rows and about columns: the system will loop from 0 to 3 to determine which columns will be removed.

Comment: and how do you determine that?

Comment: when it is 0, the col to remove is 0. when it is 1, the col to remove is 1. when it is 2, the col to remove is 2, when it is n, the col to remove is n